# Retrieve tray position on menuItem click

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to retrieve the position of the tray icon when one of the tray's menu items (`Menu.buildFromTemplate`) is clicked in order to open a window at that position.

First I though of using the tray's click event to store the bounds, but none (*click, clicked, double-click, right-click …*) emits any event.

Anyone with any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [tray.getBounds()](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/tray.md#traygetbounds-macos-windows)?